# Slow sync speed of geth

Tags: synchronization

it seems that my geth sync speed is very slow (5 blocks per minute), and it needs to process 30k blocks to get up to date, which will take forever, as it currently syncs slower than new blocks appear. My server is fast, I use ssd disks, network speed is great. When I restart geth, it initially goes to 200-300 blocks per minutes, but then goes back to 5-10. Can it be that my geth connected to slow peers? Any help will be appreciated!

My command for running geth is: /usr/local/bin/geth --syncmode full --http --http.port 8556 --http.addr "0.0.0.0" --authrpc.port 8552 --http.api eth,net,engine,admin,txpool --port 30314 --cache 16384 --authrpc.jwtsecret /home/ethereum/prysm/jwt.hex